# Rails: Form for method and password update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

little question regarding rails.

I have followed the tutorial of Michael Hartl. In chapter 9 he shows who to update users.

Step 9.1: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#sec-updating_users

I was wondering how you can update the name without having to put in the password and password confirmation into the form.

When I tried to implement this and leave out the text inputs for the password and did not permit them in the controller, the application always throws errors that the password is to short (it is probably empty). But I'm not POSTing the password? Or am I.

I would just like to have the password stay the same and just change the name for instance.

I hope you can understand me and know how to implement this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout your validator in the model. At the moment it does not allow to have no password set on saving the model

Option A: allow blank entry

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true
```

Option B: skip pw validation in certain places

```
attr_accessor :changing_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 } if: :changing_password

u = User.new(params[:user])
u.changing_password = true
u.save
```

Option C (clean OO way) : implement a form object
[3. Extract Form Objects](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/)

Comment: Thanks ! Option B did it for me